# Does Arduino Uno come with Virtual Pin support?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to recieve Data with Virtuino from my Arduino Uno 3 (Ethernet Shield) via Ethernet.

Does Arduino Uno 3 support virtual pin? If so - is there a link with the Syntax I need?

Thank you very much

Comment: have you searched for `virtuino arduino uno` - second link in google uses an ethernet shield

Comment: Thanks, I am using an ethernet shield and established a connection with Virtuino already. I did use google. Doesn't answer my question if Ardunio Uni supports virtual pins though :/

Comment: What are virtual pins?

Comment: @Majenko The library he mentions allows to map variables in the mobile app to variables in the device firmware using the so called virtual pins. It's just a way to define a data binding between the two pieces of software: you change the virtual pin state/value in one to get the same change reflected on the other end.

Comment: Ah. So the answer is: "Yes. If you write the software to do it - or install whatever libraries this Virtuino thing provides for you".

Comment: Thats right, basically what I want to do. If I google for "Arduino Virtal Pin" and similiar things I often come to "Blynk" though I need to use Virtuino. 
What I basically need is a library and/or Syntax to use virtual pins.

Comment: it appears that the `virtual pin` exists in the Android app .... when an Arduino hardware pin changes state, a message is sent to the app, which changes the state of the virtual pin ..........  changing the state of a virtual pin in the app, sends  a message to the arduino, which changes the state of the hardware pin  ..... because of the time required to send a message, you cannot use the virtual pin for fast changing pins such as PWM

Comment: @Red, the Virtuino  web site has a bunch of example sketches ..... you just have to look ....... you may also be misunderstanding what virtual pins are ...... that may be why you are not satisfied with the answers that you found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual pins are, as the name gives away, *virtual*, thus not related to the hardware you are using. Imagine you have a board with 100 pins, you have 100 physical pins and can add 1 million virtual pins (memory permitting).
In other words, the question doesn't seem to make sense to me.

**UPDATE**
If you need a bootstrap on *how* virtual pins are defined and used you could give a look at the examples published by the authors, like [these](https://virtuino.com/downloads/examples/bluetooth_example_03_virtual_memory.zip)

If that's not enough, please provide additional information on what problem you are facing and which solutions you have already attempted.

Comment: Nono, thats everything I needed. I used many of the examples the IDE provided but I didn't find this one. It's perfect. Thank you very much Roberto :)